# HTTPS protocol not working with django and nginx on ec2 instance

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, https

I have been trying to auto transfer all requests to https protocol using nginx in django in ec2 instance but i am unable to do so.. here is my nginx file..
please suggest me the problem.

nginx file

```
server{
listen 443 ssl;
server_name www.priyamarya.com;
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/project/aryapriyam/;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/project/aryapriyam/project.sock;
    }
}
server{
listen 80;
server_name priyamarya.com;
return 301 https://www.priyamarya.com;
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/ubuntu/project/aryapriyam/;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/project/aryapriyam/project.sock;
    }
}
```

i have also added this in settings.py

settings.py

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT =True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/project/aryapriyam
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/project/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - -- 
workers 3 --chdir /home/ubuntu/project/aryapriyam/ --bind 
unix:/home/ubuntu/project/aryapriyam/project.sock 
project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

i have also set my hostedzone A type record set to the alias provided by elb load balancer.

i have tried a lot of things like returning the https://sitename , and creating a different server block for both protocols but than it starts a loop in between requests. this is why i am posting the code from which i initially started. i have searched a lot but nothing is helping in regards of nginx and django both, please help.. i want all my forms request also to go through https only.

Comment: When you create 2 server blocks for each 80 and 443 config, what type of loop do you get? hhp-hhtps-http-https , https-https-https ? (You can look at it by getting to the network tab of developer tools of your browser (F12 normally).

Comment: i have edited the question with two blocks. its working now but its showing nginx welcome page not my index.html

Comment: Earlier i was getting https-https-https loop. so this time i tried using one and different server name on each block, and it worked!! but its showing nginx welcome page...

Comment: i am still stuck on this please help....@flaixman

Answer (score 0):

You need to add other **server block** for ssl and use following config for ssl

This config also redirects `http` request to `https` (*i.e ssl port 443*)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testing.com;
    return 301 https://testing.com;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/sample_project/sample_project.sock;
    }
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   listen [::]:443 ssl;
   server_name testing.com;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
   location /static/ {
           root /home/ubuntu/sample_project;
      }
   location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/sample_project/sample_project.sock;
       }

}
```

Comment: amazon does not provide ssl certificates or keys.. so i am not sure what to put in ssl_certificate and key section. its working if i use one of the domain name in each block but its showing nginx welcome page..

Comment: Can you please share snippet of your form actions?